# How to Use NVD3.JS or D3.JS library to build Dashboard in OpenERP V7?

Tags: d3.js, odoo, nvd3.js

I'm having a dataset, and I would like to visualize it in a dashboard on Odoo/OpenERP V7. Is there a way, I can import with it D3.JS or NVD3.JS charts into odoo and visualize them there? 
Else, how can I visualize a bunch of CSV files on a dashboard in Odoo/OpenERP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I used the dashboard module integrated in the OpenERP V7, using the graph tags in the xml file. Doesn't provide a high quality graphs, but, it did the job.